# Java - Caching the result of a method call

Tags: java, caching

I want to cache the result of a method call and in the code example and I looking into a Json to know if there is a property and I want to cache the result. I got this code:

````
        if (json == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String propertyValue = null;
        final ObjectNode node = objectMapper.readValue(json, ObjectNode.class);
        if (node.has(property)) {
            propertyValue = node.get(property).textValue();
        }
        return propertyValue;
    }```

how can I cache the result of:

```objectMapper.readValue(json, ObjectNode.class);```

Thank you.
````

Comment: You are asking to cache the `ObjectNode` object, however, why not cache the final result `propertyValue`? Secondly, where is the JSON data coming from? If its result of a HTTP request why not also avoid the HTTP I/O with caching? If the JSON data is coming from I/O you will not have a noticeable effect when just caching the JSON parsing stage.

Comment: Maybe you can add more code that explains where the json is coming from?